Reduce the width of the columns of the table where the text color has been changed
I applied the text color to the 3rd and 4th columns. Now I have a problem with the fact that in these columns I cannot adjust the column width.
I need all the cells of the same width, but now columns 3 and 4 are wider than the rest. How do I set the width for all cells at once?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.2cm} p{0.2cm} >{\color{cyan}}c >{\color{cyan}}c p{0.2cm} p{0.2cm} p{0.2cm} p{0.2cm} l}
        04 & 44 & 3A & 3E & B7 & 1C & 7D & 44 & one \\ 
        04 & 24 & FF & 1F & 82 & 2F & 5C & 24 & two \\ 
        00 & 44 & F3 & F3 & 1D & 1C & 7D & 44 & three --- a long line of text\\ 
    \end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}



Why did you change to c ? Try something like \begin{tabular}{*{2}{c} *{2}{>{\color{cyan}}c} *{4}{c} l}

Your table has several problems:

prescribed columns widths (0.2cm) is to small for cells contents
I wonder, why you prescribe so small column widths, does use l type column instead p{0.2cm} not gives what you after?
colored columns are of c column type, which natural width is far wider from width of other columns, which have prescribed widths. Consequently colored columns have correct width meanwhile the others not and appear narrower.

Two possible solutions:

as suggested @azetina in his comment (first example)
instead tabular use tblr of tabularraypackage (second example):

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray} % for tblr in the second example
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
    \begin{tabular}{c c
                    >{\color{cyan}}c >{\color{cyan}}c
                    c c c c l}
        04 & 44 & 3A & 3E & B7 & 1C & 7D & 44 & one \\
        04 & 24 & FF & 1F & 82 & 2F & 5C & 24 & two \\
        00 & 44 & F3 & F3 & 1D & 1C & 7D & 44 & three --- a long line of text\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}

\noindent\begin{tblr}{colspec = { *{2}{Q[c, wd=1.1em]}
                                  *{2}{Q[c, wd=1.1em, fg=cyan]}
                                  *{4}{Q[c, wd=1.1em]}
                                  l}
                      }
        04 & 44 & 3A & 3E & B7 & 1C & 7D & 44 & one \\
        04 & 24 & FF & 1F & 82 & 2F & 5C & 24 & two \\
        00 & 44 & F3 & F3 & 1D & 1C & 7D & 44 & three --- a long line of text\\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}


